# How to parse xml document having 2 roots elements with NSXMLParser in Swift?

Tags: xml, swift, element, nsxmlparser

[xml to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbTG.png)

I'm trying to parse this XML document using NSXMLParser in Swift.
My problem is that I am able to parse Properties elements such as

```
PointsButoir,Difficulte ,etc.
```

But when arrived to `Difficulte` element and closing tag of `Properties`, an error is occurred.
Here is how I'm coding this:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if (elementName == "Proprietes"){
        isProp = true;

    }
    if (elementName == "arbreRenduINF2990"){
        isArbre = true;
    }
    switch elementName {

    case "xml": break
    case "Proprietes" :break
    case "arbreRenduINF2990" :
        print("arbre")
    case "PointsButoir":
        let ptsButoir = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.ptsButoir = Int(ptsButoir)!
    case "PointsTriangulaire" :
        let ptsTriangulaires = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.ptsTri = Int(ptsTriangulaires)!
    case "PointsCible" :
        let ptsCible = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.ptsCible = Int(ptsCible)!
    case "PointsVictoire" :
        let ptsVic = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.ptsVictoire = Int(ptsVic)!
    case "PointsBilleGratuite" :
        let ptsBille = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.ptsBilleGratuite = Int(ptsBille)!
    case "Difficulte" :
        let diff = attributeDict["Nombre"] as String!
        prop.difficulte = Int(diff)!
    case "table" :
        let nbEnfants = attributeDict["nbEnfants"] as String!
        let nbreNoeuds = Int(nbEnfants)!

    case "boost": break
    case "trou":
        print("trou")
    default :
        let posX = attributeDict["posX"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(posX) {
        attObjets.posX = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let posY = attributeDict["posY"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(posY) {
        attObjets.posY = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let posZ = attributeDict["posZ"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(posZ) {
            attObjets.posZ = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let angleX = attributeDict["angleX"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(angleX) {
            attObjets.angleX = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let angleY = attributeDict["angleY"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(angleY) {
            attObjets.angleY = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let angleZ = attributeDict["angleZ"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(angleZ) {
            attObjets.angleZ = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let scaleX = attributeDict["scaleX"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(scaleX) {
            attObjets.scaleX = CGFloat(n)
        }
        let scaleY = attributeDict["scaleY"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(scaleY) {
            attObjets.scaleY = CGFloat(n)
        }

        let scaleZ = attributeDict["scaleZ"] as String!
        if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(scaleZ) {
            attObjets.scaleZ = CGFloat(n)
        }

        let objetAcharger = monObjet(name: elementName,attributs: attObjets)
        nodesAcharger.append(objetAcharger)
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?){
    if (isProp){

    }
    if(isArbre){
    }

}
 func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print("Erreur dans le parseur XML")
}
```

It seems to me that it is not able to parse next root element (arbreRenduINF2990) but I can't find the problem

Comment: Well-formed XML ***cannot*** contain more than one root element.  If you want to parse this you must split it into separate streams each containing one root element.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have to deal with only one xml file. I don't understand how to split that

Comment: You have one XML file  but you can preprocess it and split it up in memory to parse it as several distinct sections.

Comment: You don't have one *XML* file.   You have one *text* file.    As @JimGarrison said, XML cannot have more than one root element.   You have two choices, both of which require that you treat your file as ***text***, not XML, because it's not XML:  (1) Split the two root elements into two XML documents (as Jim suggested), or (2)  Wrap the two root elements with a single root element.   If everything else is fine with your "XML", ***after*** taking one of the above two routes, you'll be able to use XML parsers and tools on your data.

Comment: Posting screenshot of file is frowned upon here. Either paste everything here or use Pastebin. Remember to sanitize all sensitive information.